# Run Api code after killed the App iOS flutter -Background fatch- plugins

Tags: ios, flutter

after run the simulate Background fetch I see That in the log.
I tested using. real device iPhone 8 - iOS 13.4.1
I waited two days nothing happened.

The log:

```
2020-05-29 18:05:53.515643+0300 Runner[372:40553] [TSBackgroundFetch scheduleProcessingTask] 
2020-05-29 18:05:53.523393+0300 Runner[372:40553] [TSBackgroundFetch finish] flutter_background_fetch (2 of 2)
-[BackgroundTaskManager startPreventSuspendTimer:] BG time remaining: 20 | Total tasks: 1
2020-05-29 18:05:54.032876+0300 Runner[372:40857] -[BackgroundTaskManager startPreventSuspendTimer:] BG time remaining: 20 | Total tasks: 1
-[TSLocationManager onSuspend:] enabled? 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately, there isn't enough information here to help you. Please review (How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]. Without seeing your code there's not a lot we can help with.

Comment: Thank you for response 
I need just run code when  the user killed the app (eg: i use the app after that killed when killed I need send to the api tell me user killed )

Answer (score 0):

If the user kills your app, nothing further will happen in the background.  I take "kill" to mean a hard, force quit.  Merely hitting the Home button sends your app to the background.

Can't you just send you a note when the appDelegate receives a "applicationWillTerminate" or a "applicationWillResignActive"?